# Generate HTML Reports with cucumber 4 using JSON and screenshots

Tags: javascript, protractor, cucumber

I'm using cucumber version 4. 
I could generate a JSON file by specifying the format in the cucumber options.

Can someone tell me how to generate HTML Reports and attach screenshots.

Comment: read the explanation from https://github.com/yongcy/automation/tree/master/protractor/protractor-cucumber4-scaffold,  and the example protractor conf file in the repo

Comment: check [qaf-gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) which provides detailed [reporting](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/qaf_reporting.html) with screenshots.

Comment: @yong Thanks a lot.
Using plugins in protractor solved the issue.